# Select the C1 values having 0th line(C2) has value in C3 and all other lines(C2) having value as NULL - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1
 (
   C1 VARCHAR2(3), C2 VARCHAR2(3), C3 VARCHAR2(4)
 );

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A', '0', '1234');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A', '1', '4568');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A', '2', '5432');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B', '0', '3562');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B', '1', Null);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B', '2', Null);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C', '0', '2132');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C', '1', Null);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C', '2', '5431');
```

When you execute above query, we get the data into TABLE1 and each unique value of C1 column corresponds to 3 lines i.e. 0,1,2 (in C2 column). What is the query to select the data of column1 having its first line i.e. 0 in column2 has a value(which is not null) in C3 and all other lines of C2 have a value as Null in C3.

The answer for above example is

```
 C1    C2      C3
------------------
 B     0       3562
 B     1       Null
 B     2       Null
```

There are various rows. For each unique value of C1 can have multiple lines i.e. 0 to 100 etc. in C2 but I have taken above one as an example. In above you can see that A has values in all the 3 lines. B has value in 0th line but as Null in all other lines. C has values in 0th line and 2nd line but Null in 1st line. We need to select the unique value of C1 having value in 0th line and Null in other lines

Comment: To make sure I understand: Given the input data, you want an output that will only show distinct values from column `C1`, and specifically, those values (and **only** those values) where there is a row - for that `C1` value - where `C2 = 0` and `C3` is not `null`, and any other rows for that `C1` value, if any, have `null` in column `C3`? Aside from that, are `C1` and `C2` constrained to `not null`? Can they have duplicates (meaning, the same `(C1, C2)` values in more than one row)?

Comment: (C1,C2) together wont be repeating...Its unique...U understood correctly...C1 and C2 wont be Null

Comment: There were a few other questions. Can C1 or C2 be null (and if so, what is the desired handling). Also - the output; I re-read the question, and it seems you don't just want to return B from your given input, you want to return all the data for B (all three rows, and all three columns for those rows).

Comment: Yes I want to return all the rows related to B because 0th line of B having value and other lines of B are Null......C1 wont be null and C2 also wont be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select *
from   table1
where  c1 in (
               select c1
               from   table1
               group  by c1
               having count(case when c2 = 0 then c3 end) = 1
                  and count(c3)                           = 1
             )
order  by c1, c2
;



C1  C2  C3  
--- --- ----
B   0   3562
B   1       
B   2
```

This reads the base data twice. If you use analytic functions instead, you can have the base data read just once, but analytic functions themselves are slower than traditional aggregation. If this query works for you, but it is slow, you can try the analytic functions approach just to make sure, but I expect it will be slower, not faster.

Is column `c2` supposed to be numeric? I treated it as such, but in your sample data you gave it as strings.

Comment: Okay u can take C2 as numeric and what is lnnvl here?

Comment: @impstuffsforcse - as you can see, I removed it, since in the meantime you clarified that `c2` can't be `null`. In any case, I came up with a better solution, since you answered that `(c1, c2)` is unique; so the new version counts how many times `c3` is not null (the only values counted by `count()`) when `c2 = 0` - the answer must be 1 - and also how many times `c3` is not null **overall** (for the group defined by `c1` value) and the answer must still be 1.

Comment: `lnnvl` is a "condition" in Oracle SQL. It is true when the condition in parentheses is either false **or UNKNOWN** (due to `null` data). The `lnnvl` I had there initially, `lnnvl(c2 = 0)`, means "c2 != 0 **or c2 is null**".